# APC 1500 - F01 Code - no battery overload

Tags: apc-smart-ups

I have an APC 1500 - About a year ago, I could hear the battery back up kick in and a message would say that I was now on battery back up. There was/is no power failure and no reason for the battery to kick in. This happens about 5 times a week.

I only have a Mac Pro, 2 monitors on battery back up and a G-Drive on surge protection.

Starting a few days ago, the APS 1500 just started to have an F01 failure kicking the Mac & monitors off.  The alarm sounds.  When I go to reset, everything works fine.

The battery shows 100%.  I am using about 345 watts and the system is at 38% capacity.  It also shows that the battery will last about 13 minutes with that power.  Plenty of time to shut down normally if there is a power failure.  I can not figure out what is wrong.  There is no battery overload. Could my APC 1500 be going bad?

Comment: Same Problem, Brand new Batteries, (nothing wrong with one year old batteries) the Dealer says if not the batteries ,some charger problem. My honest opinion, APC the company, has out lived its useful life. There solution is to buy a new UPS unit.

Comment: I would suggest that you contact Schneider Electronic which is the company beyond. if its still under warranty. if its a old device I would suggest that you replace the unit.

Comment: A brownout/undervoltage can cause the line-interactive UPS to kick in. You need to check what exactly the UPS is reporting.